# Different ways of configuring webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, configuration

I'm writing scripts to deploy apps under Tomcat. There are different ways of configuring these apps:

- Keeping properties files in a source directories like WEB-INF which would mean we need to extract sources and replace those files with what we need for particular env
- Configuration based on env properties, this looks like a bad option as for me, files are more explicit and less magic, and less work on separating apps on the same machine
- There are also options to configure TOMCAT_HOME/conf/[app_name].xml and treat those properties as env vars in our apps. But in this way it won't be possible to move to Jetty for instance if we would want to do that because these files are Tomcat-specific.

Could someone provide other options and share their opinions on the listed above? Consider these criteria: easiness of configuring, portability, standards, explicitness (don't like magic, other people may not understand it), OS (main OS is Linux, but others may want to run it on Windows).

Comment: Note that using context XML files for configuration is _not_ specific to Tomcat. Jetty can use them as well: http://www.enavigo.com/2008/08/29/deploying-a-web-application-to-jetty/ , and so can JBoss. They are actually (I believe) part of the Servlet spec.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks, as for now I consider this as the best way since I would just need to keep several [app_name].xml files and put them into Tomcat without having any DBs or env settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use configuration based on env properties by using files. What I mean is that you can write a Context.xml file under the META-INF of your web application setting up the environment or configuration following this [rules](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html).

I find that using env properties provides easy configuration, is based on context and dependency injection. You can use the new java API's eg. the @Resource annotation. It will work under any application server, etc.

Comment: Yes, this is the recommended, standard way of configuring a web application. Note that the context.xml can be outside the WAR (under `APACHE_INSTALL/conf/context.xml`), that way it can be changed by admins without messing with the WAR.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend putting properties into a database table (which of course implies, your application has a datasource).

We prefer this method in our web applications for the following reasons:

- Properties are separated from the deployed artifact and application's install directory
- Peoperties can easily be accessed by database tools
- Properties can have additional attributes, like a type or a default value
- Properties can easily be changed during runtime (provided the web application has some admin page to reload them)
- Depending on the environment (e.g. development, test, production) you can have different sets of properties and load them in the same way as other master data

In cases where you don't have a database at all, another solution is just to use system properties and read them by System.getProperty(key), which is ok for a system under your control and not too many properties.

Comment: Good points. However, you still need some other way of setting config options if you put your config into the DB. Otherwise, where is your app getting its DB parameters?

Comment: @sleske: Well, the database connection settings are handled by the application's runtime environment, so for Tomcat for example it is specified in context.xml, and thus your application does not have to care about it, but uses the datasource by its name and can access the configuration table for reading its properties.

Comment: Ah interesting. So you actually combine configuration via context.xml and configuration in the DB.

Comment: @sleske: Actually, those are two different things. I specify a datasource for the container (which is done in context.xml for Tomcat), which enables my application to use a database, for whatever it needs it for. Then I also put my application properties in the database and use them by querying them at startup without having to put them in a properties file.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand. I just wanted to point out that the DB parameters (or the datasource, if you like) are arguably also part of the application setup parameters.

Comment: This looks more like enterprise solution, dunno whether it's applicable for lightweight webapp apps. Especially if it's public and anyone can take and use it.

Comment: @ctapobep: In our case it's indeed an enterprise web application, but it is not limited to it, it only depends on the fact, wheter or not your application already has a database. It's usually not worth it to introduce a database just for that, but if you already have one, it's an easy and well maintainable solution for cases where you have different environments and the requirement for changes during runtime. If it's only a one time thing if someone wants to deploy your webapp, I'd go for the properties file in WEB-INF solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it worked well using and environment variable for the conf dir: {APP_NAME}_CONF_DIR. If this is not set the application will default loading from /etc/{app_name}/conf . 
Most of the time you will not have to set the env. variable as you will use the default dir.

Comment: BTW, the app can be started from Windows as well.